# JSoup URL linking struggling

Tags: java, html, parsing, url, jsoup

I cannot get the hyperlink from this element. I have tried element.attr("href") and element.abs("href") to no avail. Here is what I am trying to extract:

```
 <p ><strong>Previous Chapter:</strong> <a href="http://www.mangahere.com/manga/mirai_nikki/v07/c031/">Mirai Nikki 31</a>
```

I want the URL from that source, but I cannot get it working.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Document doc;
try{
    doc = Jsoup.connect(currentURL).get();
    Element e = doc.getElementsByClass("reader_tip").first().children().last().children().first();
    System.out.println(e.text());
    String backPage = e.attr("href");

    loadPage(backPage);
}
catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

and the URL in question:

http://www.mangahere.com/manga/mirai_nikki/v07/c032/

It's probably something so simple I am overlooking it. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your selector to `p:contains(Previous Chapter) a`, which looks for A tags that are inside P tags which contain the text "Previous Chapter".

Full example:

```
String url = "http://www.mangahere.com/manga/mirai_nikki/v07/c032/";
String ua = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_2) AppleWebKit/537.33 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1438.7 Safari/537.33";

Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent(ua).timeout(10 * 1000).get();
Element a = doc.select("p:contains(Previous Chapter) a").first();
String backUrl = a.attr("href");

System.out.println(String.format("Back URL: %s (%s)", backUrl, a.text()));
```

Prints:

```
Back URL: http://www.mangahere.com/manga/mirai_nikki/v07/c031/ (Mirai Nikki 31)
```

Please see [Try jsoup](http://try.jsoup.org/~IX0wEJOz7aUrZh2_l5tqyplNCZE) and the [jsoup select syntax documentation](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).